# Viewport metatag

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have added to following view port metatag to my head section of PHTML file:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>`

But when I try to view it in Mobile it displays very narrow like the website is displayed only in half of screen of mobile while the other half of mobile is blank. 
Can any one please guide whats wrong? any CSS I have to add to make it look good or any change in viewport settings.
I have tried to add css 100% for viewport.

Comment: Read [this](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972) article. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Do you have a live website so we can look at it on our mobile phone?

Comment: post your css (on jsfiddle), got same problem last week and i had problem on css @media :) - anyway try add this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px){
  #yourid{
    width: px;
  }
  .yourclass{
    width: px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 360px){
  #yourid{
    width: px;
  }
  .yourclass{
    width: px;
  }
}

@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}
```

with javascript.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
var li = document.createElement('link');
li.type = 'text/css';  
var href='mobile.css';   
//var href=('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +'thesite.com/api/widgets/pages.css';
li.setAttribute('href', href);
li.setAttribute('rel','stylesheet');
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
s.appendChild(li, s);
}
```

Comment: That did fix the issues but the website seems to take a different design and display pages with layout a bit different that on actual website. Ideally With viewport I expected it to display exactly same like my Desktop version but something which fits mobile screens .Any guess whats wrong ?

Comment: Do not disable zoom (`initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;` ). That is bad practice!

Comment: @user3347166: Use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200" >` to get a very small desktop version on mobile.